# How to Update Plaso

Tags: ubuntu, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I have been trying to Google but to no avail. May I ask this community how to update my plaso on an Ubuntu/WSL?

I have tried the below:

https://plaso.readthedocs.io/en/latest/sources/user/Ubuntu-Packaged-Release.html

```
apt install plaso-tools
apt-get install plaso-tools
apt upgrade plaso-tools
```

But it keeps saying:

```
plaso-tools is already the newest version (20220724-1ppa1~focal)
```

But I can see there's a later release

https://github.com/log2timeline/plaso/releases/tag/20230717

Comment: But did you do `apt update`? Without new package lists, you will never get new versions of anything.

Comment: What is available on (e.g.) github and what you package maintainer provides (via*.deb, using apt) at a given moment will likely always differ.

Comment: Thanks @DanielB - tried - but same issue. I think what @ Hannu is saying applies however I don't know how to verify this.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that Plaso-Tools does not support Ubuntu 20.00 and I need to upgrade it to 22.00 before upgrading it :)